# Keep getting this notice error cms

Tags: php, html, sql, content-management-system

Hi im making a CMS with responsive HTML5 front
this part of the code retrieves the relevant information from url so that the relevant information can be displayed

this is the notice i am getting

**Notice: Undefined index: pid in /home/hj016/public_html/SSTW/index.php on line 7**

```
    require_once "script/connect_to_mysql.php";
// Determine which page ID to use in our query below
    if (!$_GET['pid']) {
        $pageid = '1';
    } else {
        $pageid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pid']); 
// filter everything but numbers for security
    }
```

is there any way to hide this ??

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (!isset($_GET['pid'])) {
```

basically you are calling for an undefined index even though you are trying to check if its not defined. The safe way to do this is with isset as it wont error if its not defined, because your checking existence not value.

Answer (score 1):

On a production server you would generally hide notices anyway. But checking using `isset($_GET['pid'])` would be the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
 require_once "script/connect_to_mysql.php";
    // Determine which page ID to use in our query below
    if (!isset($_GET['pid']) || empty($_GET['pid'])) {
        $pageid = '1';
    } else {
        $pageid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pid']); 
    // filter everything but numbers for security
    }
```

hows that? will make sure its set and not set to just like pid=